# Как прописать путь до контроллера

Tags: php, html, form, path

[image]

Выше приведен скрин расположения файлов в проекте. В views/RegistrationPage.php расположена html форма, в action формы мне нужно указать пусть к Controllers/RegistrationController.php. Как  я могу это сделать?

Comment: установить composer. Выстроить структуру классов по psr-4. Подключить классы в composer. Использовать классы в скриптах, используя `use` (естественно подключить composer). Тиражировать данное решение на все проекты и больше никогда не возвращаться к этому вопросу

Answer (score 1):

Вот так?

```
 use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
```

Comment: Нет, это не Laravel